# Samba mounts from remote cygwin session

Tags: ssh, cygwin, samba

I have a samba point mapped to a drive letter on a Windows XP. This is mounted automatically in cygwin when I run cygwin locally, but when I ssh into my cygwin from a remote linux machine, I can't see that samba point any more. How can I mount it manually from a remote session? I'm assuming cygwin has created a different windows user account for ssh sessions and therefore it's a permission issue (?)

Comment: the samba tag is a little misleading, this is not a samba issue per-say, it is a strictly client issue and would have the same problem with a windows server. I have seen someone else with this same problem, but I can not remember the solution. maybe net use?

Comment: thanks @hildred, net use did actually work! It's funny though, net use does not prompt me for the password. It does ask for one, but immediately returns with "System error 5 has occurred. Access is Denied". But if I pass the password with the command, it just works.